# llvm-link: Can I link .ll files having different functions with common name

Tags: llvm

I have 3 files, first file is a library code mylib.c, second is myProgram1.c and third is myProgram2.c. I need a combined llvm bitcode file. So I do the following things.

> clang mylib.c -S -emit-llvm -o mylib.ll
>
> clang myProgram1.c -S -emit-llvm -o myProgram1.ll
>
> clang myProgram2.c -S -emit-llvm -o myProgram2.ll
>
> llvm-link mylib.ll myProgram1.ll myProgram2.ll -o final.ll -S

But the problem is I have main function in both myProgram1.c and myProgram2.c. So it is unable to link saying that there is duplicate symbol.
So is there any way I can link all the 3 files through llvm-link?

Comment: And why do you have two `main`s? What you expect the linker to do with them?

Comment: You can not have the same named function more than once when you link, regardless of which linker you use.

Comment: @arrowd. I have just given a sample example. It's not necessary that there are 2 mains, there can be two 'foo()' functions in two files.

Comment: @FrankC. llvm would treat 2 different files as 2 different modules.right? So isn't there anything to differentiate like  module:myProgram1 function:main and module:myProgram2 function:main ?

Comment: Well, you can set linkage type to "internal" for these functions.

Comment: You can obfuscate the name by changing each in the `.ll` however; if the intent is that another piece of code references the original name, you will need to substitute the reference from the caller `.ll` to the now obfuscated name. `clang` ***does not*** do that for you automagically. I've done similar but you have to provide a `main` definition that calls the appropriate, now obfuscated, `main`.

Comment: @arrowd - That would work but if you are expecting an execution you will need to define `main` without `internal` somewhere.

Comment: @FrankC. I am not supposed to change the function names in .ll files. Isn't there any other way by which I can produce the .ll files from original program1.c, which will contain the name of the function like moduleName.functionName or anything similar like this, so that I can differentiate the function names.

Comment: @KetanPatil - no there is not. You'd have to change the source or the `.ll` files somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea to use `llvm-extract` that maybe work.

Suppose we have following two source code.

$ cat prog1.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f1() {
  printf("f1\n");
}

int main() {
  f1();
  return 0;
}
```

$ cat prog2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void f1();

void f2() {
  printf("f2\n");
}

int main() {
  f1();
  f2();
  return 0;
}
```

First we compile it with clang.

```
$ clang -c -emit-llvm prog2.c
$ clang -c -emit-llvm prog1.c
```

Then list the symbol defined in bytecode with llvm-nm.

```
$ llvm-nm prog1.bc |grep -v main
---------------- T f1
                 U printf
```

And then use llvm-extract to extract everything exclude main.

```
$ llvm-extract -func=f1 prog1.bc -o prog1_f1.bc
```

At last, link with llvm-link.

```
$ llvm-link prog2.bc prog1_f1.bc -o link.bc  
$ llvm-dis link.bc -o -
```

It seems the bytecode is valid.

```
; ModuleID = 'link.bc'
source_filename = "llvm-link"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

@.str.4 = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"f2\0A\00", align 1
@.str = external hidden unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8], align 1

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define void @f2() #0 {
entry:
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str.4, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret void
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  call void (...) bitcast (void ()* @f1 to void (...)*)()
  call void @f2()
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define void @f1() #0 {
entry:
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret void
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0, !0}

!0 = !{!"clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)"}
```

Comment: Very creative... I was so focused on linking and collisions, the idea of a final transformation as you've noted slipped my mind. +1 for the level of creativity, hopefully this cuts the mustard!

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the point of using the llvm-nm command here?